# IBM IoT Foundation Device Management

Tags: iot, device-management

I would like to use IBM IoT Foundation Device Management for an important customer. It wants the solution on premises and not on the cloud. Can I use IBM IOT Foundation on premises?

Comment: The IBM IoT Foundation was renamed and is now known as Watson IoT Platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a Local version of Watson IoT Platform available.

With IBM's Local offering, you can have IoT Platform deployed your own data center or one of your choosing – flexibility to deploy whenever you choose.

With Local, you own the hardware, running in your own datacenter.  Find more information in this [announcement][1].

[1]: https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/blog/2016/03/30/announcing-watson-iot-platform-local/ - link not working